# MacOSX or AppleScript: get current URL from Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, applescript

How can I get the current URL from Firefox (3 or 4)? All solutions I have found so far either don't work (e.g. those with `"class curl"`) or are ugly hacks which are no solution for me (sending key presses to copy the URL to clipboard).

Comment: @Powertieke: I am using Chrome. But this should go into an application which I want to sell to other users and I doubt that I could just tell them "please use Chrome or Safari instead of Firefox".

Comment: Maybe you can get the python `webbrowser` module to fire off an inline javascript which could talk back to the script using google gears or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I have one solution now: I am reading it out of the current session store of Firefox. This works but it is always up to 10 seconds out-of-date.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/albertz/foreground_app_info/blob/master/mac/app-scripts/url%20of%20Firefox.py

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate

tell application "System Events"

keystroke "l" using {command down}

keystroke "c" using {command down}

end tell
```

Comment: "... ugly hacks which are no solution for me (sending key presses to copy the URL to clipboard)"

Comment: This solution has been repeated all over the 'net, and at least on current fast Apple hardware suffers from a nearly 100% repeatable "race condition" where FF won't have activated before System Events does its thing.  It works to stick a big fat delay (2 sec or more, in my informal trials) in between the two tells, but that piles hack upon hack.  Note: the delay statement needed is literally "delay 2", for those unfamiliar with AppleScript.

Answer (score 2):

Easy, if you install two components:

- the `mozrepl` firefox extension ([github](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki))
- and [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) perl module

If you have installed both, the following command

```
perl -MWWW::Mechanize::Firefox -E 'say WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(tab=>'current')->base()'
```

will print the topmost active firefox url, in like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296995/macosx-or-applescript-get-current-url-from-firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

**Since Firefox 87** you can use native AppleScript GUI scripting to get the current URL. That's because Firefox now has [support for VoiceOver](https://blog.mozilla.org/accessibility/voiceover-support-for-macos-in-firefox-87/).

First enable Firefox support for VoiceOver by going to `about:config` and setting the `accessibility.force_disabled` property to `-1`. Note that VoiceOver doesn't have to be enabled, only the support in Firefox. (Extra info at [2].)

After that, you can use:

```
tell application "System Events" to get value of UI element 1 of combo box 1 of toolbar "Navigation" of first group of front window of application process "Firefox"
```

---

[1]: Enabling VoiceOver support makes Firefox expose the internal structure of its window for GUI scripting.
[2]: For extra info and a non-permanent option (toggling `AXEnhancedUserInterface` via AppleScript) look at [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=781090#c10).

Comment: This is a weird one. Under normal circumstances, I get the same error and result with Firefox v90 under Sierra. However, when VoiceOver is enabled the url is returned. I can't support the answer though as this prerequisite is a non-standard condition for most users. As it stands this isn't a good workaround.

Comment: Sorry, only now realized that I had an app which enabled VoiceOver support in FF. Added a section about how to enable it manually, without having VoiceOver enabled globally. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

A window's URL is not exposed via the Applescript API; not even a window's tabs. The only way you'll be able to get it is through GUI scripting.

Firefox's Applescript implementation is simply awful, and I don't know why they even bother.

Comment: What do you mean by GUI scripting? I thought that AppleScript is also mostly made for GUI scripting.

Comment: GUI Scripting is an aspect of Applescript which allows for the direct maninpulation of controls, like buttons, checkboxes, and the like.

Comment: How can this be done for Firefox? And doesn't it require that the application uses Cocoa GUI elements? Because I think FF doesn't use those.

Comment: I don't do GUI scripting myself as I find it problematic and too easily prone to error, but there is an intro here: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html Firefox should support this by way of Mac OS X, but I can't tell you definitively either way.

Comment: I tried a bit like that to find the text box. For other applications, I was able to get a list of all GUI elements (buttons, text boxes, etc.). But for Firefox I was not. So I guess this is not possible.

Comment: One thing I've learned is that if something can't be had by either the API or GUI scripting, then it's not doable. GUI scripting is typically the last chance. Like I wrote in my answer Firefox's Applescript API is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3's AppleScript implementation is lame enough that you have to resort to copying the URL out of the Location field, as shown in the last post is [this thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=32237).

Comment: This seems to be the only viable option. System events does not see any ui elements below the main window space... I can honestly say that this is the worst applescript support ever.

Comment: Well, this is absolutely no option for me. I don't want to invalidate users clipboard. And I want to check for the current URL about every 10 seconds.